# How to prove that $T_f(0.x_1x_2\ldots x_n\ldots)=0.x_{f(1)}x_{f(2)}\ldots x_{f(n)}\ldots$ preserve measure?

Tags: measure-theory

For each $x\in[0,1]$, let $(0.x_1x_2\ldots x_n\ldots)_2$ be the infinity binary expansion of $x$.

Given  a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, define $T_f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$T_f(x)=T_f\left((0.x_1x_2\ldots x_n\ldots)_2\right)=(0.x_{f(1)}x_{f(2)}\ldots x_{f(n)}\ldots)_2$$ Prove that if $E\subset[0,1]$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $T_f(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mu(T_f(E))=\mu(E)$.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really the statement that the map $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to [0,1]$, $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\mapsto0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$, is an isomorphism of measure spaces (modulo subsets of measure $0$). If you fix $a_1,\dots,a_n$ then the measure of the resulting subset is (in both spaces) $2^{-n}$.